# How to fetch the cursor data in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE get_new
AS
    CUST_ID varchar2(100);
    ROUTERNAME_N VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID,ROUTERNAME INTO CUST_ID,ROUTERNAME_N
    FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
    WHERE rownum > 3;

    my_ename INTERFACE_ATTLAS.TRAFFIC_CUST_ID%TYPE;
    my_salary INTERFACE_ATTLAS.ROUTERNAME%TYPE;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO my_ename;
        FETCH c1 INTO my_salary;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_ename);
    end loop;
end;
```

I am new to oracle and stored procedure. I am trying to get the rows using cursor fetch, and getting following error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "C1" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite it like this:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE get_new
AS
    my_ename INTERFACE_ATTLAS.TRAFFIC_CUST_ID%TYPE;
    my_salary INTERFACE_ATTLAS.ROUTERNAME%TYPE;
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID,ROUTERNAME
    FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
    WHERE rownum > 3;
BEGIN
  open c1;    
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO my_ename, my_salary;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_ename);
    end loop;
  close c1;
end;
```

Do not forget to open and close cursors. It always will print nothing because of `rownum > 3;` You wanted to type: `rownum < 3;`, didn't you?

Comment: No errors are displaying, but no data is displaying.

Comment: as I said: "It always will print nothing because of rownum > 3;" You have to change `rownum > 3` to `rownum < 3` if you want to see two records only, or get rid of it, if you want to see every record of the table

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE get_new
AS
    CUST_ID varchar2(100);
    ROUTERNAME_N VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID,ROUTERNAME INTO CUST_ID,ROUTERNAME_N
    FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
    WHERE rownum > 3;

    my_ename INTERFACE_ATTLAS.TRAFFIC_CUST_ID%TYPE;
    my_salary INTERFACE_ATTLAS.ROUTERNAME%TYPE;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO my_ename;
        FETCH c1 INTO my_salary;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_ename);
    end loop;
end;
```

Cursor should be declare in the declaration part. Then have to open in begin-end section. In the declaration section you can not assign value to variable. When you are fetching value you can not select randomly value form cursor,

modified code:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE get_new
AS
   no mean --CUST_ID varchar2(100);
  no means -- ROUTERNAME_N VARCHAR2(100); 

    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT deptno,job
    FROM emp;

    my_ename emp.deptno%TYPE;
    my_salary emp.job%TYPE;

BEGIN
    open c1;

    LOOP

       fetch c1 into my_ename,my_salary;
       -- FETCH c1 INTO my_ename;
        --FETCH c1 INTO my_salary;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_ename);
    end loop;
end;

execute get_new.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably declare your cursor and your variables `my_ename` and `my_salary` in the dedicated section, i.e. before the `BEGIN`, and then open your cursor:

```
IS
    CUST_ID varchar2(100);
    ROUTERNAME_N VARCHAR2(100);
    C1 sys_refcursor;
    my_ename INTERFACE_ATTLAS.TRAFFIC_CUST_ID%TYPE;
    my_salary INTERFACE_ATTLAS.ROUTERNAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN C1 for
    SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare the Cursor before BEGIN. You would use no INTO clause in the cursor declaration.  Then you would have to OPEN the cursor. Then you would `FETCH INTO my_ename, my_salary`, not one after the other (you fetch rows, not columns). `WHERE rownum > 3` returns no rows. As you don't want a first row, you will never get a second, third and fourth either.

And you can use an implicit cursor which is easier to deal with (no need to open, fetch and close explicitely):

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (
    select traffic_cust_id, routername 
    from interface_attlas
    where rownum <= 3
  ) LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.traffic_cust_id || ': ' || rec.salary);
  END LOOP;
END;
```